# Getting started with laravel (4) models

Tags: laravel, models, laravel-4

I'm trying out this model-thing, but I can't really get my grasp of it.

For the moment I have two tables (companies and sellers) "companies" as a column named "cResponsibleID" which I want to map to "sID" in "sellers".

models/Companies.php

```
class Companies extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'companies';
    protected $primaryKey = 'cID';

    public function sellers() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Sellers','sID');
    }
}
```

models/Sellers.php

```
class Sellers extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'sellers';
    protected $primaryKey = 'sID';

    public function companies() {
        return $this->hasMany('Companies','cResponsibleID');
    }
}
```

I then want to do something like `Companies::with('sellers.sName')->get()` to "translate" cResponsibleID to sName.

Maybe I'm all out wrong.
Thankful for all help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try printing the result of:

```
<?php
$company = Companies::with('sellers')->get();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($company->sellers);
```

And see how they're build up, I blieve the sellers.ANYTHING construction is only meant for multiple nested relations.
for example of a Seller has an Address as a relation, it would be Companies::with('sellers.address')

Comment: Then I get `Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$sellers`

Comment: It looks like this:
`[relations:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [sellers] => 
                        )` so it seems that the relations doesn't work.